# R: label variables based on their prefix

Tags: r, label

Im new to R and trying to label multiple but not all variables of my data at the same time. Specifically, I want to label the variables starting with "pol". I tried to combine the select and the set_variable_labels command in the following manner:

```
cp14 <- cp14 %>% 
  select(matches("pol")) %>%
  set_variable_labels(cp14,
                      labels = "Interest in politics")
```

I would like all variables that include "pol" to be labelled as "Interest in politics". This however does not work. Any advice on how to do this in a similar or completely different manner is greatly appreciated.
My data looks something like this, but with many more variables:

```
structure(list(pol_interest_w1 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.5), pol_interest_w2 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, NA, 0.25, 0.5), pol_interest_w3 = c(0.5, 
0.5, 0.25, NA, 0, 0.5), pol_interest_w4 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, NA, 
0, 0.5), pol_interest_w5 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, NA, 0, 0.5), pol_interest_w6 = c(0.5, 
0.5, 0.25, NA, 0, 0.5), pol_interest_w7 = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.25, NA, 
0.25, 0.5), new_col = c(0.75, 0.5, 0.25, NA, 0.25, 0.5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you please add your expected output?

Comment: 1. Please show us what you expect your output to be. It's not clear what you are intending to accomplish by "labeling" your output. 2. Any time your code depends on some packages, please load the packages at the start of your code. In this case, it looks like you're using `dplyr` and maybe `labelled`, so you can use e.g. `library(dplyr)` at the start. 3. You're currently passing one value to a function that is expecting multiple values, plus also passing your cp14 object twice (%>% is passing a set of columns from it and then the cp14 again is the same as giving the function that). Likely issu

Comment: as stated by the others in the comments an expected output is needed to help with the question. Perhaps take a look at ```grep``` and ```gsub``` of base r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a couple ways. For either solution, start by creating a vector of variable names starting with `"pol"`. (I use `stringr::str_starts()` here; you don’t want to use `select()`, as in your code, which is for subsetting columns from your dataset.)

```
library(stringr)
library(labelled)

pol_vars <- names(cp14)[str_starts(names(cp14), "pol")]
```

Then, you can make a named list of labels, and pass it to the `.labels` argument of `labelled::set_variable_labels()`.

```
pol_labels <- setNames(
    as.list(rep("Interest in politics", length(pol_vars))),
    pol_vars
)

cp14 <- set_variable_labels(cp14, .labels = pol_labels)
```

Alternatively, you could loop over the variable names and assign labels using `labelled::var_label()`.

```
for (v in pol_vars) {
    var_label(cp14[[v]]) <- "Interest in politics"
}
```

Both approaches yield the same result:

```
#> var_label(cp14)

$pol_interest_w1
[1] "Interest in politics"

$pol_interest_w2
[1] "Interest in politics"

$pol_interest_w3
[1] "Interest in politics"

$pol_interest_w4
[1] "Interest in politics"

$pol_interest_w5
[1] "Interest in politics"

$pol_interest_w6
[1] "Interest in politics"

$pol_interest_w7
[1] "Interest in politics"

$new_col
NULL
```